Umbraco Rich Text Editor Insert/Edit Link Button Not Working
My Umbraco Document Type includes a property with a Rich Text Editor, which is used to edit the content for a product in Merchello within the Umbraco Backoffice. However, when I try to edit the content by clicking the Insert/Link button in the editor, the dialog doesn't appear. Instead, I see an error in the browser's Console Log.
Could this be a caching issue? I'd like to republish the site, but it's currently in Production.


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'properties') at DependencyHandler.axd
It's complaining that the editorState.current is Null. I don't have any custom JavaScript code for this.

